# Selenium - How to remove &nbsp from my text value

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I am trying to use this xpath to find the number of elements that have a value between X and Y. The problem I am facing is since there is &nbsp in the HTML, and the code doesn't detect the text value.

Xpath:

```
    //div[@class="prix"]/div[2]/div[2]/span[1][number(translate(text(), ",", ".")) > 4 and number(translate(text(), ",", ".")) < 43]
```

HTML :

```HTML
    <div class="d-flex-inline productPrice">
      <span>4,42&nbsp;</span>
      <span>€/HT</span>
    </div>
```

I tried with `replace(text()," ","")` and `replace(text(),"\&nbsp;\","")` and other combinations but nothing worked.

Comment: I thought [number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/number) stripped whitespace?

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to use xpath simply to locate the element and treat fetched string using your programming language.

For example, in Java, you can use a regex to replace anything that is not a number or dot with an empty character, thus keeping only the number representation.

```
String onlyNumbers = str.replaceAll("^\d+(\.\d+)*$", "");
```

Comment: yeah normaly but for less code i try to get the size of that xpath so if the size is equal to what i have i want need to creat a "for" function to test every article that shows

Answer (score 0):

If your HTML Code is this,

```
<body>
    <div class="d-flex-inline productPrice">
        <span>4,42&nbsp;</span>
        <span>€/HT</span>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Then you can get only the number and ignore the space or any other character from the text you get from getText() using this,

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='d-flex-inline productPrice']/span[1]")).getText().replaceAll("[^\\p{ASCII}]|&nbsp;| ", "");
```

Here is my working code,

```
try {
            WebDriver driver;
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir") + "//chromedriver");
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            driver.get("file:///home/eclipse-workspace/demo/test.html");
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='d-flex-inline productPrice']/span[1]")).getText().replaceAll("[^\\p{ASCII}]|&nbsp;| ", ""));
            
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            driver.close();
            driver.quit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This a common scenario faced by testing companies who provide automation testing services.

To remove spaces from the text we can have a regular expression check and replace HTML

```
String myStr = "4,42&nbsp";
myStr = myStr.replaceAll("[\\s\\u00A0]+$", "") ;
```

It removes non breaking spaces in the input string.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the nbsp using `normalize-space()`. Based on the html snippet  your provided , I can find detect the text value:

```
//div[@class="d-flex-inline productPrice"]/span[normalize-space()="4,42\u00a0"]
```

It has already been answered here -  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55355770/how-can-i-find-the-exact-value-using-xpath-in-selenium-webdriver-for-text-that-c/55359370#comment97447308_55359370